# How to reference a Vue data property from another data property

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning Vue.JS and all my attempts to reference the **dashboards** property from the **currentDashboard** data expression result in 'dashboards is not defined'. Is Vue somehow evaluating the **currentDashboard** expression prior to **dashboards** or do I need some qualifier to reference it, this does not help?

```
vue = new Vue({
el: '#dashboard',
data: {
    dashboards: store.getDashboards(),
    currentDashboard: dashboards[0],
}
```

})

Comment: Hi Mikee, did you solve your problem? If yes, try to update your question to help others or if the answer helped mark it as resolved to keep S.O. clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think that one solution is that you could use the `computed` method for it, because `dashboards[0]` are not defined in the same `created` cycle. Try with something like:

```
data: {
    dashboards: store.getDashboards(),
},
computed: {
  currentDashboard: function () { return this.dashboards[0] }
}
```

This way the variable is defined when you make the `currentDashboard` call and you don't have to refactor the Vue.js call for this var.

**Edit:**
Yes, if you want to know why, as points Joel, in the official documentation you can read:

> If you know you’ll need a property later, but it starts out empty or
> non-existent, you’ll need to set some initial value.

In this case, the data() method starts with all the values in a queue, without assigning it, and for this, the starting value is `undefined`.
Here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that is actually what I ended up doing to get things working as I am learning.  However this is really not a computed value it's just a reference and I would like to know why I can't seem to do this?

Comment: This is because when the data object is created it needs to know all the values upfront, you can't construct a property based on another property since the base object hasn't been created yet. If you had calculated store.getDashboards() prior the new Vue instance, then you could have referenced it.

Answer (score 2):

you can create `dashboard` variable before you return `data` properties so that you can use it multiple times in `data` properties.

```
vue = new Vue({
el: '#dashboard',
data() {
    let dashboard = store.getDashboards()
    dashboards: dashboard,
    currentDashboard: dashboard[0],
}
```

I hope this is helpful